# Icecast with Liquidsoap not working

Tags: ubuntu-server, icecast, liquidsoap

All;
**Ubuntu 18.04** - Icecast / LiquidSoap / opam /  (liquidsoap-daemon)
**Installed**: taglib mad lame Vorbis cry ssl samplerate magic opus
**Plugins**: liquidsoap-plugin-all

**System Specs**:

```
-System - VirtualBox
-CPU = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
-Memory = 1969MiB (2GB assigned to VM Client)
```

I have been messing with this for a while now and to no avail.
I have this thread that is now closed, that has near about everything that you would need to look at about my setup. [icecast request parsing failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766636/icecast-request-parsing-failed/50774979)

The playlist I'm testing:

```
 #!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
 # Log dir
set("log.file.path","/var/log/liquidsoap/radioliq.log")

 # Music
myplaylist = playlist("/home/UserName/music-store/")
 # Some jingles
jingles = playlist("/home/UserName/music-store/jingles/jingles.m3u")
 # If something goes wrong, we'll play this
security = single("/home/UserName/music-store/Sec.mp3")

 # Start building the feed with music
radio = myplaylist
 # Now add some jingles
radio = random(weights = [1, 4],[jingles, radio])
 # And finally the security
 radio = fallback(track_sensitive = false, [radio, security])

  # Stream it out
output.icecast(%vorbis,
  radio, host = "192.168.2.20", port = 8000,
  password = "********", mount = "test.ogg")
```

When I run this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/liquidsoap restart
```

I get this

```
Stopping liquidsoap channels: no script found in /etc/liquidsoap
Starting liquidsoap channels: radio1.liq OK
```

It shows starting radio1.liq, however, it is STOPPING, because it cannot find anything in that directory, however. That is where it is picking up on the radio1.liq file.

When I run

```
sudo systemctl status liquidsoap
```

My output is this:

```
● liquidsoap.service - LSB: Starts the liquidsoap daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/liquidsoap; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-06-12 17:47:52 EDT; 3h 0min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1312 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/liquidsoap start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 12 17:47:47 liquid-ice systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts the liquidsoap daemon...
Jun 12 17:47:52 liquid-ice liquidsoap[1312]: Starting liquidsoap channels: radio1.liq OK
Jun 12 17:47:52 liquid-ice systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts the liquidsoap daemon.
```

As you can tell, the **Active** is (**exited**) when other times, it is (**running**) like Icecast is. However, I usually have to do a reboot on the system, in order to get it to show (**running**)
I just did a reboot, and it is still showing (**exited**), this is the first time that it has not changed to (**running**). And usually it will give me an error that I have to fix something, but it is not doing it now.

```
● icecast2.service - LSB: Icecast2 streaming media server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/icecast2; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-06-12 17:47:50 EDT; 3h 1min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1338 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/icecast2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 2289)
   CGroup: /system.slice/icecast2.service
           └─1403 /usr/bin/icecast2 -b -c /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml

Jun 12 17:47:48 liquid-ice systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Icecast2 streaming media server...
Jun 12 17:47:48 liquid-ice icecast2[1338]:  * Starting streaming media server icecast2
Jun 12 17:47:50 liquid-ice icecast2[1338]:    ...done.
Jun 12 17:47:50 liquid-ice systemd[1]: Started LSB: Icecast2 streaming media server.
```

when I open the web interface, I only get the following tabs (pages)

```
[Admin] | [Version]
```

All the other pages are all blank:

```
[Server Status] => Nothing, completely blank.
[Mountpoint List] => Active Mountpoints (This is all it shows on the page)
```

I also changed the username in the /etc/init.d/liquidsoap

```
user=username
group=username
```

Username Is what I am logged in as. And then gave permission to my user over the locations.

```
/etc/liquidsoap/radio1.liq
/run/liquidsoap/
```

using the following scripts:

```
sudo chmod o+w /run/liquidsoap/
sudo chmod o+w /etc/liquidsoap/radio1.liq
```

Here is the latest error log from the icecast error.log

```
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO sighandler/_sig_die Caught signal 15, shutting down...
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO main/main Shutting down
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO fserve/fserve_shutdown file serving stopped
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO slave/_slave_thread shutting down current relays
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO slave/_slave_thread Slave thread shutdown complete
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO auth/auth_shutdown Auth shutdown
[2018-08-08  02:22:18] INFO yp/yp_shutdown YP thread down
[2018-08-08  02:22:19] INFO stats/stats_shutdown stats thread finished
[2018-08-08  02:22:19] INFO main/main Icecast 2.4.3 server started
[2018-08-08  02:22:19] INFO connection/get_ssl_certificate No SSL capability
[2018-08-08  02:22:19] INFO stats/_stats_thread stats thread started
[2018-08-08  02:22:19] INFO yp/yp_update_thread YP update thread started
```

Exerts from the radio.log file

```
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [dynamic.loader:3] Could not find dynamic module for fdkaac encoder.
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [dynamic.loader:3] Could not find dynamic module for aacplus encoder.
..........
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [frame:3] Using 44100Hz audio, 25Hz video, 44100Hz master.
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [frame:3] Frame size must be a multiple of 1764 ticks = 1764 audio samples = 1 video samples.
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [frame:3] Targetting 'frame.duration': 0.04s = 1764 audio samples = 1764 ticks.
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [frame:3] Frames last 0.04s = 1764 audio samples = 1 video samples = 1764 ticks.
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [decoder:3] Method "MAD" accepted "/home/darkice/music/Security/sec.mp3".
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [single:3] "~/music/Security/sec.mp3" is static, resolving once for all...
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [threads:3] Created thread "generic queue #1".
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [threads:3] Created thread "non-blocking queue #1".
2018/08/09 04:35:03 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Loading playlist...
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] No mime type specified, trying autodetection.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [playlist.basic:3] Wrong mime type audio/mpeg for playlist!
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [playlist parser:3] No format found
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Could not parse playlist: Not_found
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Got an empty list: keeping the old one.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Loading playlist...
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Playlist is a directory.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Successfully loaded a playlist of 1 tracks.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [single_6363:3] Prepared "/home/darkice/music/Security/sec.mp3" (RID 0).
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [test(dot)ogg:3] Connecting mount test.ogg for source@192.168.2.4...
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [test(dot)ogg:2] Connection failed: 401, Authentication Required (HTTP/1.0)
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [test(dot)ogg:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [threads:3] Created thread "wallclock_main" (1 total).
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [clock.wallclock_main:3] Streaming loop starts, synchronized with wallclock.
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [decoder:3] Method "MAD" accepted "/home/darkice/music/List/01 Send Her To Me.mp3".
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [test(dot)ogg:2] Connection failed: 401, Authentication Required (HTTP/1.0)
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [test(dot)ogg:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [threads:3] Created thread "wallclock_main" (1 total).
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [clock.wallclock_main:3] Streaming loop starts, synchronized with wallclock.
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [fallback_6368:3] Switch to single_6363.
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [carrzkiss:3] Prepared "/home/darkice/music/List/01 Send Her To Me.mp3" (RID 3).
2018/08/09 04:43:34 [fallback_6368:3] Switch to random_6366 with transition.
2018/08/09 04:35:05 [random_6366:3] Switch to musicList.
2018/08/09 04:35:09 [test(dot)ogg:3] Connecting mount test.ogg for source@192.168.2.4...
2018/08/09 04:35:09 [test(dot)ogg:2] Connection failed: 401, Authentication Required (HTTP/1.0)
2018/08/09 04:35:09 [test(dot)ogg:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
```

[I followed this page here, to get the logging to start.](https://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Liquidsoap#Logging_Output_to_a_File)

Is there something I am missing here? is there something else that needs to be installed, in order to make liquidsoap function properly?
I followed this tutorial on the installation. [Create an internet radio station with Icecast and liquidsoap](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-internet-radio-station-icecast-and-liquidsoap)

I really do not know what else to add to this. I have gone through everything and even did some extras while writing this up. Please let me know if there is anything else that you may need for me to check on. And please, have a look at my other thread, for more information on what I have set up here. [icecast request parsing failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766636/icecast-request-parsing-failed/50774979)

running the following code.

```
curl -v 192.168.2.4:8000 >/dev/null
```

gives me this.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.2.4:8000/
*   Trying 192.168.2.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 192.168.2.4 (192.168.2.4) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.2.4:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: Icecast 2.4.3
< Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 18:28:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 1144
< 
{ [1144 bytes data]
100  1144  100  1144    0     0  95333      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  101k
* Closing connection 0
```

Thank You.
**Wayne**

Comment: latest Icecast `error.log` and Liquidsoap `radioliq.log` would help. As last status indicated a problem in the latter. Also please kindly note the name is *Icecast* without camel case, thank you.

Comment: I am now visiting this issue again. After a little while of working on a networking issue, and a new out-of-office job. I will post new information requested once I have collected it.

Comment: Updated with the latest error.log information.

Comment: Nothing relevant in that bit of Icecast log. What about `/var/log/liquidsoap/radioliq.log`? Also, make sure `/var/log/liquidsoap/` is a writeable location for your user.

Comment: I finally got the log working for liquidsoap. Just need to write up everything I did, to make it start working and logging. Updated information will be added in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Updated with Radio.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I messed with Icecast2 and Liquidsoap.
However, I did just that a few weeks ago.
After struggling for some time, I figured it out after getting help from another person and watching a video.
It was all a permissions issue.

Once you create your user, "Icedemo."
(logged in as root)

```
adduser Icedemo
```

Give user SUDO rights.

```
usermod -aG sudo Icedemo
```

Now give permissions to Icedemo to all the folders.

```
/opt/liquidsoap/Playlists/
/var/log/liquidsoap/
/etc/icecast2/web/
/etc/icecast2/admin/
```

Use the following script to give permissions.

```
cd /opt
sudo chown -Rv icedemo:icedemo liquidsoap/
cd /var/log/
sudo chown -Rv icedemo:icedemo liquidsoap/
cd /etc/icecast2/
sudo chown -Rv icedemo:icedemo web/
sudo chown -Rv icedemo:icedemo admin/
```

Leave permission the same for the icecast.xml file.

Log in as your user **Icedemo**

```
su Icedemo
```

Once you have done all the above and your script is properly formatted. Something like this.

```
# !/home/iceadmin/.opam/default/bin/liquidsoap
# log dir
set ("log.file.path","/var/log/liquidsoap/basic-radio.log")
set("scheduler.fast_queues",1)
 # Music
music = playlist("/opt/liquidsoap/playlists/RadioOne.m3u",mode="normal",reload_mode="watch")

# Start building the feed with music
radio = music

# Stream it out
output.icecast(%mp3(bitrate=256,samplerate=44100,internal_quality=0,id3v2=true,stereo=true,stereo_mode="stereo"),
name="Radio",
encoding="UTF-8",
host="192.168.2.203",
port=8000,
password="hackme",
icy_metadata="true",
description="Internet Radio Station",
mount="Radio",
mksafe(radio))
```

We will need to restart each service.

```
#Restart IceCast   
sudo systemctl restart icecast2
#Check status of IceCast  
sudo systemctl status icecast2
(Ctrl+Z to go to prompt)
```

Next, we will need to do the same to Liquidsoap.

```
#Restart Liquidsoap
sudo systemctl restart radio.liq-liquidsoap
#Check status of  Liquidsoap
sudo systemctl status radio.liq-liquidsoap
(After checking the status, you can use (Ctrl+Z to go to prompt))
```

Your output of the Liquidsoap status should look similar to mine.

```
Icedemo@linuxcore-03:~/liquidsoap-daemon$ sudo systemctl status radio.liq-liquidsoap
● radio.liq-liquidsoap.service - radio.liq Liquidsoap daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/radio.liq-liquidsoap.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-05-24 03:47:01 UTC; 4s ago
       Docs: http://liquidsoap.fm/
    Process: 54678 ExecStart=/home/Icedemo/.opam/default/bin/liquidsoap /home/Icedemo/liquidsoap-daemon/script/radio.liq-run.liq (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 54680 (liquidsoap)
      Tasks: 9 (limit: 2251)
     Memory: 17.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/radio.liq-liquidsoap.service
             └─54680 /home/Icedemo/.opam/default/bin/liquidsoap /home/Icedemo/liquidsoap-daemon/script/radio.liq-run.liq
May 24 03:47:01 linuxcore-03 systemd[1]: Starting radio.liq Liquidsoap daemon...
May 24 03:47:01 linuxcore-03 systemd[1]: Started radio.liq Liquidsoap daemon.
```

If the above is showing:  Active: active (running)
Next, check your Icecast webpage, and you should see your mountpoints, and your radio should be working.
To access the radio station in our example script above would be.

```
(local) 192.168.2.203:8000/Radio
```

This will load the player in its own browser window, and your stream should start on its own. If not, click the PLAY button.

That's it; that is how you get your streaming radio to work.
I hope this helps others out.

Wayne

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that I think I have enough information/data, let's pick this apart:

> ```
> 2018/08/09 04:35:03 [single:3] "~/music/Security/sec.mp3" is static, resolving once for all...
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [single_6363:3] Prepared "/home/darkice/music/Security/sec.mp3" (RID 0).
> ```

Your liquidsoap internal 'fallback' configured by 'security' just became available.

> ```
> 2018/08/09 04:35:03 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Loading playlist...
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] No mime type specified, trying autodetection.
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Could not parse playlist: Not_found
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [Jingle(dot)mp3:3] Got an empty list: keeping the old one.
> ```

There is no playlist for jingles. I'm guessing it will just ignore that.

> ```
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Loading playlist...
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Playlist is a directory.
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [musicList:3] Successfully loaded a playlist of 1 tracks.
> ```

"/home/darkice/music/List/01 Send Her To Me.mp3" is the only file in the specified directory.

> ```
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [test(dot)ogg:3] Connecting mount test.ogg for source@192.168.2.4...
> 2018/08/09 04:35:05 [test(dot)ogg:2] Connection failed: 401, Authentication Required (HTTP/1.0)
> ```

It's trying to connect to your Icecast server, but Icecast rejects the connection.
The most likely reason for this is that the password doesn't match the one configured as `<source-password>` in the Icecast config.

You will find details as to why the connection failed in the Icecast error.log at the timestamp `2018/08/09 04:35:05` - please note that there may be an offset if this is a different computer and the system time of either machine is not synchronized by e.g. NTP.

Comment: I fixed the password issue. So now it connects. How would I test it, to see if it is actually streaming the media?

Comment: You should now see an active mountpoint on the Icecast status website. Opening `http://192.168.2.4:8000/test.ogg` in a media player (e.g. VLC) or Browser (Firefox, Chrome) should start playing the stream.

Comment: that is the problem. I don't have NO active Mountpoints on the web page, it is blank. And loading the URL you provided, I have tried several times before asking, and I get the 404 - The file you requested could not be found The error log for Icecast shows: "/usr/share/icecast2/web/test.ogg" No such file or directory

Comment: The "no such file" message is just a fallback check. It also checks if there is a file in webroot, not only if there is a stream present. // You said "So now it connects", yet you say no stream shows. In that case please provide both liquidsoap log AND icecast error.log